# Uneven (lengths columns in) pivot table in R

Tags: r, casting, pivot-table, reshape

I am loading my data from a mysql with two columns: id, rt

id corresponds to many rts in practice (my poorly designed table):

```
      id   rt
 1 5129052 2  
 2 5129052 2
 3 5129052 5
 4 5129052 6
 5 7125052 0
 6 7125052 1
 7 7125052 2
 8 7125052 4
 9 7125052 6
10 7125052 7
```

I want to create a pivot table like the one below. The first column is just the number of row, nothing particular.

```
     5129052 7125052
  1    2       0
  2    2       1
  3    5       2
  4    6       4
  5   NA       6
  6   NA       7
```

If posible also sort the values in ascending order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I find most of the answers here to be a bit of overkill. Here are two more suggestions. Both depend on creating a secondary "id" that represents the number of values present for an existing id.

```
## Create a secondary "id"
df$id2 <- ave(as.character(df$id), df$id, FUN = seq_along)
df  ## Your new "df"
        id rt id2
1  5129052  2   1
2  5129052  2   2
3  5129052  5   3
4  5129052  6   4
5  7125052  0   1
6  7125052  1   2
7  7125052  2   3
8  7125052  4   4
9  7125052  6   5
10 7125052  7   6
```

#### Option 1: Base R's `reshape`

Just clean up the variable names if required, and you're good to go.

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "id2", timevar = "id")
   id2 rt.5129052 rt.7125052
1    1          2          0
2    2          2          1
3    3          5          2
4    4          6          4
9    5         NA          6
10   6         NA          7
```

#### Option 2: `dcast` from "reshape2"

Cleaner syntax, and cleaner output.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, id2 ~ id, value.var="rt")
  id2 5129052 7125052
1   1       2       0
2   2       2       1
3   3       5       2
4   4       6       4
5   5      NA       6
6   6      NA       7
```

As to your bonus question? These solutions both output a regular `data.frame` so `write.csv` can be used on them directly.

Comment: That's great to output data.frames. I don't mind about the syntax however `dcast` gives me a random sorting in the columns.

Answer (score 5):

Does your answer have to be a matrix?  Because a matrix doesn't really make much sense to me in this situation.  Seems like a list would be a more practical solution, allowing for the different lengths of the `rt` vectors for each `id`.  For example:

```
lapply(split(df$rt, df$id), sort)
```

Comment: Love the simplicity. Bonus question thought: if I write it in a csv (let's just say: `lapply(mylist, write, "test.csv", append=TRUE, ncolumns=500)` or if you have a better command ) the lists are lines. Can I transpose them?

Comment: In that case, you might want to use an approach something like @GeoffreyAbsalom suggested:  `tmp <- lapply(split(df$rt, df$id), sort)
maxl <- max(sapply(tmp, length))
res <- sapply(tmp, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, maxl - length(x))))` then use `write.csv()`.

Answer (score 2):

Using what Jean V.Adams has provided you can create a dataframe from that using the following.

```
 dat <- read.table(text= "  id   rt
 1 5129052 2  
 2 5129052 2
 3 5129052 5
 4 5129052 6
 5 7125052 0
 6 7125052 1
 7 7125052 2
 8 7125052 4
 9 7125052 6
 10 7125052 7",header=TRUE,sep="")

 tmp <- split(dat$rt,dat$id,sort)
 res <- sapply(tmp,function(x) { c(x,rep(NA,maxl - length(x)))})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cbind the elements of the list:

```
# Loading dataset
df <- structure(list(id = c(5129052L, 5129052L, 5129052L, 5129052L, 
7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L), 
    rt = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L)), .Names = c("id", 
"rt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

# cbind the list output
do.call(cbind,split(df$rt, df$id))

#Output: the values of the first list are recycled instead of NAs 
#      5129052 7125052
#[1,]       2       0
#[2,]       2       1
#[3,]       5       2
#[4,]       6       4
#[5,]       2       6
#[6,]       2       7

# A.N. Spiess wrote a cbind.na function http://rmazing.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/dont-fill-me-up/#comments
    cbind.na <- function (..., deparse.level = 1)
{
 na <- nargs() - (!missing(deparse.level))
 deparse.level <- as.integer(deparse.level)
 stopifnot(0 <= deparse.level, deparse.level <= 2)
 argl <- list(...)
 while (na > 0 && is.null(argl[[na]])) {
 argl <- argl[-na]
 na <- na - 1
 }
 if (na == 0)
 return(NULL)
 if (na == 1) {
 if (isS4(..1))
 return(cbind2(..1))
 else return(matrix(...)) ##.Internal(cbind(deparse.level, ...)))
 }
 if (deparse.level) {
 symarg <- as.list(sys.call()[-1L])[1L:na]
 Nms <- function(i) {
 if (is.null(r <- names(symarg[i])) || r == "") {
 if (is.symbol(r <- symarg[[i]]) || deparse.level ==
 2)
 deparse(r)
 }
 else r
 }
 }
 ## deactivated, otherwise no fill in with two arguments
 if (na == 0) {
 r <- argl[[2]]
 fix.na <- FALSE
 }
 else {
 nrs <- unname(lapply(argl, nrow))
 iV <- sapply(nrs, is.null)
 fix.na <- identical(nrs[(na - 1):na], list(NULL, NULL))
 ## deactivated, otherwise data will be recycled
 #if (fix.na) {
 # nr <- max(if (all(iV)) sapply(argl, length) else unlist(nrs[!iV]))
 # argl[[na]] <- cbind(rep(argl[[na]], length.out = nr),
 # deparse.level = 0)
 #}
 if (deparse.level) {
 if (fix.na)
 fix.na <- !is.null(Nna <- Nms(na))
 if (!is.null(nmi <- names(argl)))
 iV <- iV & (nmi == "")
 ii <- if (fix.na)
 2:(na - 1)
 else 2:na
 if (any(iV[ii])) {
 for (i in ii[iV[ii]]) if (!is.null(nmi <- Nms(i)))
 names(argl)[i] <- nmi
 }
 }

 ## filling with NA's to maximum occuring nrows
 nRow <- as.numeric(sapply(argl, function(x) NROW(x)))
 maxRow <- max(nRow, na.rm = TRUE)
 argl <- lapply(argl, function(x) if (is.null(nrow(x))) c(x, rep(NA, maxRow - length(x)))
 else rbind.na(x, matrix(, maxRow - nrow(x), ncol(x))))
 r <- do.call(cbind, c(argl[-1L], list(deparse.level = deparse.level)))
 }
 d2 <- dim(r)
 r <- cbind2(argl[[1]], r)
 if (deparse.level == 0)
 return(r)
 ism1 <- !is.null(d1 <- dim(..1)) && length(d1) == 2L
 ism2 <- !is.null(d2) && length(d2) == 2L && !fix.na
 if (ism1 && ism2)
 return(r)
 Ncol <- function(x) {
 d <- dim(x)
 if (length(d) == 2L)
 d[2L]
 else as.integer(length(x) > 0L)
 }
 nn1 <- !is.null(N1 <- if ((l1 <- Ncol(..1)) && !ism1) Nms(1))
 nn2 <- !is.null(N2 <- if (na == 2 && Ncol(..2) && !ism2) Nms(2))
 if (nn1 || nn2 || fix.na) {
 if (is.null(colnames(r)))
 colnames(r) <- rep.int("", ncol(r))
 setN <- function(i, nams) colnames(r)[i] <<- if (is.null(nams))
 ""
 else nams
 if (nn1)
 setN(1, N1)
 if (nn2)
 setN(1 + l1, N2)
 if (fix.na)
 setN(ncol(r), Nna)
 }
 r
}

# Which can be used to produce the desired output
do.call(cbind.na,split(df$rt, df$id))

#     5129052 7125052
#[1,]       2       0
#[2,]       2       1
#[3,]       5       2
#[4,]       6       4
#[5,]      NA       6
#[6,]      NA       7
```

Comment: this function is in `qpcR`, it's just not exported, i.e. install `qpcR` and use `qpcR:::cbind.na`

Answer (score 0):

Highly ugly, but workable solution:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(5129052L, 5129052L, 5129052L, 5129052L, 
7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L, 7125052L), 
    rt = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L)), .Names = c("id", 
"rt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

> df
        id rt
1  5129052  2
2  5129052  2
3  5129052  5
4  5129052  6
5  7125052  0
6  7125052  1
7  7125052  2
8  7125052  4
9  7125052  6
10 7125052  7
```

Count the entries:

```
t1 = table(df$id)
> t1

5129052 7125052 
      4       6
```

Initialize the matrix:

```
   foo = matrix(NA,max(t1),length(t1))
```

Populate the matrix:

```
for (x in names(t1)){foo[1:t1[x],x] = sort(df$rt[df$id==x])}

> foo
     5129052 7125052
[1,]       2       0
[2,]       2       1
[3,]       5       2
[4,]       6       4
[5,]      NA       6
[6,]      NA       7
```